# MySQL 5.7 JSON_MERGE combine with GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: json, mysql-5.7, merge, concat

we have table with JSON column
for example simple:

```
{"a": 1}
{"b": 2}
```

run JSON_MERGE query

```
select JSON_MERGE('{"a": 1}','{"b": 2}')
```

result correct:

```
{"a": 1, "b": 2}
```

run the GROUP_CONCAT query

```
select GROUP_CONCAT('\'',json_text,'\'') from t_json
```

result

```
'{"a": 1}','{"b": 2}'
```

but if try to combine both of them:

```
SELECT JSON_MERGE((select GROUP_CONCAT('\'',json_text,'\'') from t_json))
```

return error:

```
Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'JSON_MERGE'
```

any ways for merge JSON documents from group operation?

Comment: An excellent question.  It seems like Oracle may have overlooked the need for a `JSON_GROUP_MERGE()` (a name I just made up) aggregate function that builds a json array of the objects from each row.  Or maybe it's there -- I haven't found it in the docs.  This seems like a big hole in otherwise-useful functionality.

Answer (score 4):

Assemble desired JSON using string functions and then cast it into JSON.

Example data

```
create table item (itemName varchar(200), itemProperties json);

insert into item values
('sword', '{"damage": 20, "durability": 300}'),
('magical sword', '{"damage": 30, "magical damage": {"fire": 5},
                    "durability": 400}'),
('dummy', '{}'),
('spellbook', '{"spell": "lightning bolt", "charge": 10}');
```

Query to merge all `itemProperties` together

```
select cast(
  concat('{',  -- wrap everything in root object '{ ... }'
    group_concat(
      -- strip parenthesis from individual item representation
      -- '{"foo": 1}' -> '"foo": 1'
      substring(itemProperties, 2, length(itemProperties) - 2)),
  '}')
as json) allProperties
from item
-- skip empty JSON values to avoid getting extra comma during 
-- group_concat
where itemProperties != JSON_OBJECT();
```

Resulting JSON

```js
{
  "spell": "lightning bolt",
  "charge": 10,
  "damage": 20,
  "durability": 300,
  "magical damage": {
    "fire": 5
  }
}
```

Several caveats:

- Behaviour of this snippet is different from `JSON_MERGE()`, for example:

  - When two or more properties have the same name their values are
    overwritten instead of being merged into array of values
  - It can't merge objects with arrays
- Solution as presented only works with objects as a top level entity
  and not with arrays. It can be modified to work with arrays.
- If relies on string representation of JSON objects beginning and 
  ending with curly brackets `{}`. This might change in future versions 
  of the server.

Comment: Thank You for idea - add one level of CONCAT + substring work in some simple cases, but not in all, also are You test this query? It not work as is (if You public it as answer for all)

Comment: It would be great if you could explain when this query won't work so that future readers will know straight ahead if this query would work for their case. Also I've fixed the query syntax.

Comment: first of all - where json != JSON_OBJECT(); will return error "UNKNOWN column json". About global - it also outside my original question and I think about it when test after asking, but You can compare result with JSON_MERGE('{"a": 1}','{"b": 2}',"a": 3}') - this is realistic scenario, so the problem is deeper than asked by me

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've expanded description of limitations of the snippet.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL v5.7.22 onwards you should be able to use `JSON_ARRAYAGG` to select grouped attributes as a json array. Something like:

```
SELECT id, JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT("a", t.a, "b", t.b)) as json from table t group by id;
```

This should return an array of json objects as second attribute in result set

```
| id | json |
-------------
| 1 | [{"a": "a-value-1", "b", "b-value-1"}, {"a": "a-value-2", "b": "b-value-2"}] |
```

Answer (score 1):

Would this work?:

```
CONCAT("[", GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(json_text AS JSON)),"]")
```

I use the following to build up object arrays:

```
CONCAT("[", GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_OBJECT("tbl", assoc.tbl_child, "id", assoc.id_child)), "]")
```

Comment: I believe OP is trying to generate a JSON object with two key-value elements. This would simply add square brackets around the string with the two objects. As the other answers noted, the fundamental problem with the OP's functionality is that they've got a single string with the text of two JSON elements in it, and they want `JSON_MERGE` to interpret it as those two elements, not a single string. It's a variation on the old "I have `@list = '1,2,3,4,5`; why don't I get the rows with those IDs back when I do `WHERE id IN (@list)`?

Answer (score 0):

`JSON_MERGE` need at leas 2 parameters,

I've found a solution but it is not robust :/.

I work with array but it should approximatively work with object.

```
SELECT
    label,
    REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(list_json SEPARATOR '%SEP_ARRAY%'), ']%SEP_ARRAY%[', ', ')
FROM some_table
GROUP BY label;
```

There is two point of failure :

- replace `]%SEP_ARRAY%[` there is a little risk, but relatively safe
- and GROUP_CONCAT limit the length of concatenation, you can set the max with `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len=100000;`. More info here https://stackoverflow.com/a/12003748/5774156